Keeping hardware powered up!
The tag hardware is a very rare tag on RE.SE



HW questions make up just 6% of the total questions on the site. Seeing that reverse engineering hardware is in scope and in many cases, has overlapping problems with software reverse engineering, I think having more hardware questions on the site will make RE.SE an even better resource. However, this also means that we need more hardware professionals to get involved in the community.
How should we go about this? How do we get more hardware professionals involved?

Update: March 2014
Currently, just 4.5% of the questions are hardware. Lets try to get the number up!

I looked around a bit and it seems that we haven't answered a lot of "trivial questions" about hardware yet. I started to ask one I came up with: How to dump flash memory with SPI. 
As we know, SE encourage answering your own questions and it may be a good idea to ask and answer those "trivial questions".

You should edit your question to make it less broad. I said it was trivial in the sense that you should just be looking this up in a datasheet. If you don't believe that is the case edit your question to explain why. In fact you probably should split that question into at least 3 different questions however if you don't give a target device you are likely to recieve equally vague and generic answers. Which will have little value for someone else.

I asked a question about two weeks ago with the "hardware" tag: Using MIPS EJTAG functionality in OpenOCD . It was upvoted a couple of times, but there was no other response. No comments saying it was a bad question, references to other sites, or answers. Similarly, the next newest hardware question (Where can i find unix/linux tool for fuzzing for kill-switches?) didn't get any answers though it did get a couple of comments. 
Maybe promoting this site on some hardware hacking forums would attract the kind of people who could answer and ask the kinds of questions we want under the "hardware" tag. 

So it got upvotes and no comments that it's a bad question. What could possibly be the message here? The fact that no one answered could have to do with no one else having done it on MIPS or with no one using your particular probe. In short, it could be too specific for the people currently in the community.

As mentioned by @0xC0000022L, the reason for this is because we may be missing the necessary expertise. Some promotion activities are on, have a look at [meta-tag:site-promotion]. Go ahead and share RE.SE wherever you get the chance!
